# Some characters (e.g. brackets) are coming encoded in Spring @RequestBody. How to decode them?

Tags: java, json, spring, character-encoding

Let's consider this fragment of code:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/getFiltered", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<OraPhysicalGoodMiniDataWrapper> getFilteredProducts(@RequestBody OraSalesOfGoodsFilters filters) {
    return oraProductListController.getFilteredProducts(filters);
}
```

`filters` parameter has String named `searchValue`.

**The problem is**: when I pass for example `searchValue: "(2016)"` in json, Spring controller receives `searchValue=&#40;2016&#41;`.
I tried to decode it with Java *URLDecoder* but it didn't work.

**And my question is**:
is there any Java method which could decode all such characters in String? Or should I write my own method?

Comment: Apache common text: StringEscapeUtils unescaping, or java 9: `s = s.replaceAll("\\&#([xX]?\\d+);", m -> new String(new int[] { Integer.decode("0" + m.group(1)) }, 0, 1));`

Comment: Thanks @JoopEggen. Method unescapeXml() from StringEscapeUtils  works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem solution. using javascript or spring settings.

**Javascript**

```
var param = {
    "searchValue": "(2016)"    
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data:  JSON.stringify(param),
    contentType:"application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    url:  '/test/filter',

    error: function() {
        // error
    },                
    success: function(returnJSON) {
        // success
    }    
}):
```

**Spring settings**

Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

servlet.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
    <list>    
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                <list>
                    <value>text/html;charset=UTF-8</value>
                    <value>application/json;charset=UTF-8</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>            
    </list>
    </property>                        
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Joop Eggen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984823/joop-eggen) mentioned in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50812533/some-characters-e-g-braces-are-coming-encoded-in-spring-requestbody-how-to?noredirect=1#comment88630510_50812533) - the `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(String value)`method proved to be helpful.

It's kind of werid that it's *`unescapeXml()`*, not *`unescapeJavaScript()`* (which is not working), because I pass the value on frontend as JSON (not XML) from JavaScript, but I'm glad it works.